# xmlstarlet sel output new line between values

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have the following XML

```
<process id="test">

</process>
<process id="test2">

</process>
```

I do get the correct values from the attributes but I want to have them separated on by a new line for further processing.

When using the command

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(process/@id" "example.xml)"
```

I can see the two are separated because it does return 2

The command used to  retrieve the attributes is the following

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "process/@id" "example.xml"
```

**Question :**

Can the output be returned with a new line for each attribute?
If not could it be done with xmllint?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was looking at this for 2 days and i found the following page:

http://www.geekfarm.org/wu/muse/XmlStarlet.html

This clarified a lot to me

I have used the following command to achieve the line breaks

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "process" -n -v "@id" "example.xml"
```

Comment: To get newlines with the `-n` flag, the `-m` option is required. I.e. when you use `sel -t -c "expression" -n some.xml`, instead use `sel -t -m "expression" -c "." -n some.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

My starting point was not XML, but HTML, so I had to first convert HTML --> XML.

```
xmllint -html -xmlout  file.html > file.xml
```

Then I use the Dany's hint above:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//html/body/table/tr/td[2]/b/text()' -c .  -n file.xml 2> /dev/null
```

Then I got output on separate lines:

```
test
test2
```

Of course the xpath was different, but the goal - separate lines was achieved.